# Highchart circle position by jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

```
function(chart) { // on complete
    var xpos = '50%';
    var ypos = '53%';
    var circleradius = 102;

    // Render the circle
    chart.renderer.circle(xpos, ypos, circleradius).attr({
        fill: '#7EBA00',
    }).add();
}); 

//position updating based on window size
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var wd = $(window).width();
    if (wd < 361) {
        //alert(wd);
        chart.renderer.circle().cx = '60%';
    } 
});
```

How can I add `x` or `y` position values using jQuery to a circle which is created in highchart SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep rendered object in a variable and then (in resize events) refer to that, calling attr().

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2aap3285/

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var wd = $(window).width();
    if (wd < 361) {
        circle.attr({
            cx: 100
        });
    }
});
```

The cx param should be defined as number not percent.